# Datadog count metric dropping with multiple containers

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, datadog

I am incrementing a Datadog counter in python:

```
from datadog import initialize
from datadog import ThreadStats
stats.increment('api.request_count', tags=['environment:' + environment])
```

And have set the metric type to "count" and the unit to "requests per none" in the metadata for the metric.

The code runs in a docker container on a kubernetes node in a Container Engine in Google Cloud... I have docker-dd-agent (https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent) running on each node.

I can move the container to any node and it logs around 200 requests per minute. But as soon as I scale it up and launch a second container, it only logs around 100 requests per minute. If I scale down to one container again, it spikes to 200 rpm again:

[image]

What could be causing the requests to drop or get overwritten from other pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use dogstatsd instead of threadstats? If you're already running the dd-agent on your node in a way that's reachable by your containers, you can use the `datadog.statsd.increment()` method instead to send the metric over statsd to the agent, and from there it would get forwarded to your datadog account.

Dogstatsd has the benefits of being more straight-forward and of being somewhat easier to troublehsoot, at least with debug-level logging. Threadstats sometimes has the benefit of not requiring a dd-agent, but it does very little (if any) error logging, so makes it difficult to troubleshoot cases like these.

If you went the dogstatsd route, you'd use the following code:

```
from datadog import initialize
from datadog import statsd
statsd.increment('api.request_count', tags=['environment:' + environment])
```

And from there you'd find your metric metadata with the "rate" type and with an interval of "10", and you could use the "as_count" function to translate the values to counts.

Comment: Thanks. The calls to statsd don't seem to be making it to the dd-agent. I have set DD_APM_ENABLED and LOG_LEVEL to "DEBUG", but can't see where they are disappearing. I haven't been able to add the --link dogstatsd:dogstatsd argument in my deployment, if that is necessary.

Comment: ah, yeah, you may need to add the `--link dogstatsd:dogstastd` argument to the run command of your python container, and you may also need to add the `-p 8125:8125/udp` to the run command of the dd-agent container. I'm referring to this doc, for reference: https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent#dogstatsd-from-the-host

i think in K8 that would translate to adding this to your daemonset: https://gist.github.com/stephenlechner/04feda283916d6df2ffb2f8b5e20376d

Comment: Thanks. If I add `--link dogstatsd:dogstastd` under `args:
        - --link dogstatsd:dogstatsd` I get the following error: "Failed to start container with docker id 34225fd5a91f with error: Error response from daemon: Container command '--link dogstatsd:dogstatsd' not found or does not exist." How do I add the command to the deployment of the python container?

Comment: And if I add the link command to the dd-agent daemonset I get: "/entrypoint.sh: line 187: exec: --: invalid option". I've also tried with the image name of the python container.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I'm seeing that [linking is technically deprecated on the docker side anyway](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/). And looking closer at the [Datadog kubernetes instructions](https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#agent/kubernetes) (step 3, specifically), it actually sounds like for K8 all you have to do is add the piece from the gist i shared. I think the linking may be something that K8 handles somehow.

Comment: To answer the question, when datadogHQ receive different payloads with the same timestamp, I think datadog will take the latest one instead of aggregating it. Explanation [here](https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972589-Data-aggregation-with-dogstatsd-Threadstats-Am-I-seeing-the-exact-values-sampled-in-my-code-How-and-why-is-the-aggregation-performed-). Using datadog agent will aggregate it at client side before sending to datadogHQ and hence no duplicated payload.

Answer (score 0):

In the python script I was initializing with an api key:

```
from datadog import api
from datadog import initialize
from datadog import statsd
options = {
    'api_key':'#######'
}

initialize(**options)
```

And sending some events

```
api.Event.create(title=title, text=text, tags=tags)
```

When I changed it to initialize like this, it started working with the dd-agent:

```
initialize(statsd_use_default_route=True)
```

I didn't need the link command (--link dogstatsd:dogstastd).

With that setup it now works in the staging environment, but not in production. :/

Comment: Good work! That will send events over the API and rule out the UDP communications entirely. Very odd that that would work for staging and not production though. There must be some subtle difference somewhere...